# How could I make this active onclick getElementById?

Tags: html, forms, dom, onclick, getelementbyid

** I want to select a photo but using the tag "p". I did was write onclick and getElementById for use the tag input but it does not work. I have no idea what to do.**

```
   <nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar bg-light border">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-link text-uppercase"
        onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('open_file').submit();">
          Visualizar File</p>
      </li>
      <input id="open_file" type="file" style="display: none;">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#">Visualizar Contenido Final</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of Submit() use document.getElementById('open_file').click(), i reproduced the code and tested it, I hope its helpful..

always make sure to check your console for your code errors and make it a habit to print your code results to the console that will be helpful to troubleshoot your code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav class= "navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark scrolling-navbar bg-light border">
    <ul class="nav">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <p class="nav-link text-uppercase"
        onclick="event.preventDefault(); document.getElementById('open_file').click();">
          Visualizar File</p>
      </li>
      <input id="open_file" type="file" style="display: none;">
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link text-uppercase" href="#">Visualizar Contenido Final</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</body>
</html>
```